# prestashop on xampp admin page not opening

Tags: prestashop-1.7

After installing Prestashop 1.7 on XAMPP, I can't open the admin page. But the shop is opening fine. I get error saying

> **localhost** is currently unable to handle this request.

Answer (score 1):

What version of XAMPP? In V3.2.2 PrestaShop 1.7 works fine.
One thing, do you rename the folder admin? **You have to rename it**, for example: admin234ps.
Regards.

Comment: I tried to use your method, but no help. I am using PS 1.7 on XAMPP version 3.2.2. Please help me out. Screenshots can be found [here](https://imgur.com/a/KRedz).

Comment: For me also admin is not working ... PS version is 1.7 xampp version 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop earlier than 1.7.3 is not compatible with PHP 7.2 .

Here is the ticket:
http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-4444

On February 28, 2018 new version 1.7.3.0 was released which doesn't contain the fix (according to the ticket above it should be available in 1.7.3.1).